Closed form for regularized Rayleigh quotient
Let $A \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$ and $b \in \mathbb R^n$.
Assume $A$ is full rank.
I am interested in optimizing the following expression over all $x$ on the unit sphere:
$$
\max_{x \in \mathbb S^{n-1}} x^T A^T A x + 2 b^T A x
$$
I know that

$\max_{x \in \mathbb S^{n-1}} x^T A^T A x= \lambda_{\mathrm{max}} (A^TA) = \sigma_{\max}^2(A)$ using the Rayleigh-Ritz Theorem
$\max_{x \in \mathbb S^{n-1}} b^T A x = \max_{x \in \mathbb S^{n-1}} \|A^Tb\| \|x\| \cos\theta = \|A^Tb\|$

So I can get an upper bound on the objective function:
$$
\max_{x \in \mathbb S^{n-1}} x^T A^T A x + 2 b^T A x \leq \lambda_{\max}(A^TA) + 2\|A^Tb\|
$$
However, I am wondering is there a closed form expression, perhaps using some cool linear algebra tricks I haven't considered?

Edit: We can also try to solve this using Lagrange multipliers by rewriting $x \in \mathbb S^{n-1}$ as $\|x\|_2^2 = x^Tx = 1$. Then, the loss function is
$$
L(x) = x^T A^T A x + 2 b^T A x + \lambda(1 - x^Tx)
$$
and the derivative is
$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial x} = 2A^TAx + 2A^Tb - 2\lambda x = 0
$$
but I'm unsure where to go from here.

Writing $A$ in terms of its singular value decomposition and re-expressing the vectors in the associated orthonormal bases will allow you to reduce this to the case where $A$ is diagonal and positive definite.

The following isn't a closed-form solution, but it does give us a way to compute the maximum value of the objective function:
As noted in the question, the Lagrangian is
$$
L(x) = x^T A^T A x + 2 b^T A x + \lambda(1 - x^Tx) \,,
$$
and its derivative is
$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial x} = 2A^TAx + 2A^Tb - 2\lambda x = 0 \,.
$$
Grouping like terms, we get
$$
(A^TA - \lambda I)x = -A^Tb \,,
$$
which lets us write $x$ as a function of the dual variable $\lambda \in \mathbb R$ when $(A^TA - \lambda I)$ is invertible:
$$
x(\lambda) = -(A^TA - \lambda I)^{-1} A^Tb \,.
$$
However, only vectors such that $\|x(\lambda)\| = 1$ are possible solutions.
Therefore, we can restrict our search to values of $\lambda$ that are roots of the secular function
$$
f(\lambda) = \|x(\lambda)\|_2^2 - 1 \,.
$$
From this point forward, we can just use a scientific computing library to find the roots of $f$ and pick the root that maximizes the objective.

Here's an example of $f(\lambda)$ for a random $A$ (full rank) and $b$ with $n=3$. The function is discontinuous at the eigenvalues of $A^TA$ because $(A^TA - \lambda I)$ is not invertible at those points. In every pair of $A$ and $b$ I've generated, the largest root of $f$ is always the optimal $\lambda^*$, but I can't yet prove if this should always be the  case.

